# Is log x + log y monotonically increasing with respect to x + y?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, logarithms, monotone-functions

We know $\log x + \log y = \log(xy)$ which is a monotonically increasing function with respect to the product $xy$.

I am wondering if $\log x + \log y$ is still a monotonically increasing function of the sum $x+y$?

Comment: $\log 2+\log9=\log 18<\log 25=\log5+\log5$ though $2+9>5+5$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. What have you tried? Have you tested some examples? Please [edit] the question to show us your work so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

For example, $\log 2+\log9=\log 18<\log 25=\log5+\log5$,

though $2+9=11>10=5+5$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little to add to the intuition. The other answer is correct.

One thing I'm confused about the question is that the query is not well-defined: log(xy) can take different values even if you know the value of x+y.

You can plot log(xy) on WolframAlpha and imagine "scanning across the graph" using hyperbolas xy=c (y=c/x) where you adjust (increase, for example) c. You can see such hyperbolas are "level sets" of f.

However, trying to do the same with diagonal lines x+y=b doesn't make sense at all.

All this fundamentally comes down to the fact that log turns multiplication into addition

Comment: Thanks! This is a really interesting analysis! I wish I knew it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be fixed and let $0 < h \le \frac M2$.  Then $\lim_{h\to 0}(\ln h + \ln(M-h)  = -\infty$ and $\lim_{h\to \frac M2} (\ln h + \ln(M-h)) = 2\ln \frac M2 = 2\ln M - \ln 2$.

$\ln a + \ln b$ with restriction $a + b = M$ has no lower bounded value.

Comment: wondering why $\lim_{h\to 0}(\ln a + \ln(M-h)  = -\infty$ holds? Isn't it converges to $\ln a + \ln M$?

Comment: The $a$ was a typo.  $\lim_{h\to 0} (\ln h + \ln (M-h)= -\infty$ as $\ln(M-h) < \ln M$ and $\ln h \to -\infty$.